# ProggresDialog & Web service's response

Tags: android, json

Im trying to dynamicly load listview.

Firstly,getting first ten data from web serives and adding it to listview.
For every ten row proggress dialog should appear when getting data.
If I dont use dismis, proggres dialog appear.
If I use dismis, proggresbar does not appear or appear and dismissed never shown in screen.
While getting response from web services screen stucks for 1-2 sec. It should not be. 
Here is my code

```
 public void setMessageList(int rowsArea){


     ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(AdminMessages.this, "", "Loading...");
     progressDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

     List<NameValuePair> parameter = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
      String url_confirmation =getInstance.getInstance().getUrl()+"getspecificrowmessages.php";
        parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rowsarea", Integer.toString(rowsArea)));
        JSONObject  json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_confirmation,"POST", parameter);

        try { 
            int success = json.getInt("result"); 
            if(success == 1) { 

             JSONArray messages = json.getJSONArray("messages"); 
                for(int i=0;i<messages.length();i++){
                    JSONObject c = messages.getJSONObject(i);

                    String subject=c.getString("theSubject");
                    Integer id=c.getInt("id");
                    Integer msgId=c.getInt("msgId");
                    String senderName=c.getString("sender_name");
                    String receiverName=c.getString("recipient_name");
                    String dateTime=c.getString("dateTime");
                    String theFileNames=c.getString("theFileNames");
                    messageDetailList.add(new MessageListDetail(subject,senderName,receiverName,dateTime,theFileNames,id,msgId));

                }
                page+=10;
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 


 }
```

Comment: use asynctask for that..

Comment: it can be...depends on how you use it...

Comment: I dont think It will solve the problem.Because after dismis progressDialog cant be useable

Comment: try `new` keyword..
`ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
   progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.show();`

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you should use a [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) instead, and manage its visibility with `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` for showing it, and `setVisibility(View.GONE)` for hiding it.

Comment: I have to use proggress Dialog

Comment: what is the reason to use the dialog instead of the view?

Comment: firstly I use  DrawerLayout on main on layout. Added items appear weird. Secondly listview cover all heights and there are some fix about it but should use linearlayout after drawerloyout but this time my code gives some errors and could not find it. asked stackoverflow  and no answer